# Monitor directories and sub directories for file created and get the first 7 characters of file created?

Tags: linux, bash, directory

I want to monitor a directories + sub dir and get the first 7 characters of file that created in the folder or sub folder. I'm using these codes for my problem :

```
inotifywait -mqr /path/ -e create |
    while read path file ; do
    line=$(head -c 7 $file) ;
    echo $line ;
    done;
```

but when I run the code it won't print only succeeded for some text file (first 7 character = "setruk"), and not print anythings for some text file (first 7 characters = "kukuryu"). Can anyone help me ? pleasee ?

Comment: Maybe quote your variables? If the filename contains spaces, your code won't work.

Comment: I already using quote, but it still not working.

Comment: I can't see any other problem with the code. Add `set -x` at the beginning to see an execution trace.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is the output of `inotifywait`:

```
$ inotifywait -mqr . -e create 
./test/ CREATE five
./test/ CREATE six
./test/ CREATE seven
```

I don't know if you get the `CREATE` part, but you're probably missing the path to the directory. You likely want:

```
inotifywait -mqr /path/ -e create |
    while read path action file ; do
    line=$(head -c 7 "$path$file") ;
    echo $line ;
    done;
```

If you don't have the `CREATE` part in the line, just change the `head` command to include the `$path` part of the filename:

```
line=$(head -c 7 "$path$file") ;
```

What's probably happening is that files in sub-directories are not getting their characters printed but files in the main directory are.

Comment: Arya, can you update your post with your current code? Please also include the output of your `inotifywait` command when you don't pipe it to the `while` loop. Additionally, try testing a while loop that just echos the path and filename and post that output.